# Extracting information from list<>

Tags: java, instagram

I have a list containing a lot of information, but the thing is that I only want the information that contains the term "id" e.g. id = 1234567.

Is there any way to do this?

Using Instagram API with Java Wrapper(jInstagram).

Code:

```
MediaFeed mediaFeed = instagram.getRecentMediaFeed(userID);
List<MediaFeedData> mediafeed = mediaFeed.getData();
```

Sample Output:

```
[data=[MediaFeedData [caption=Caption [createdTime=1401623528, 
from=FromTagData [fullName=NO, id=1366594603,
id=733193759076381317, text=3]
```

Comment: can you show us a sample list?

Comment: What type are the elements of this list?

Comment: explain your question a bit more, add details and your code

Comment: Is it a `List` of `String`, or `Integer`...?

Comment: Edited with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find value in List Use `ForEach` Loop

***FOR EXAMPLE*** Say you have `List` of `String` values

```
for(String s:list)
{
if(s.contains("12345"))
 {
 //Do what you want
 }
}
```

Here you have List of `Object` than Iterate through list like this

***AGAIN FOR EXAMPLE***

```
  for(MediaFeedData obj:list)
    {
    if(obj.data.toString().contains("12345"))
     {
     //Do what you want
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model list

```
List<MyModel> model=new ArrayList<MyModel>();

public class MyModel{
private String id;
private String name;
private String age;
//Getter & Setter Method
}

model.add("1","name1","19");
model.add("2","name2","20");
```

After added element itreate your list

```
for(int i=0;i<model.size();i++){
  sout(model.get(i).getId());//here you can get id from your list.
  sout(model.get(i).getName());
  sout(model.get(i).getAge());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, you have a list of strings and want to extract  ones that starts with "id =".

```
          String str[] = {"xyz","id=1234","abc","id=35345"};
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str);
    for(String str1:list)
    {
        if(str1.startsWith("id ="))
            //your logic here.This will give you element 2 & 4                }
```